# How to declare "propTypes" for React Hooks using React.useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-proptypes, react-context

Given an app environment where typescript is not an option und React Hooks are used.

When using a context with ...

`const myContext = useContext(MyContext)`

...how would one declare the context signature in a way we know it from the propTypes-concept?

Would React use such a declaration for warnings?

I try to assure a warning is shown for my component if the context signature changes one day.

Comment: React doesn't validate custom hooks or in-built hooks props. I completely recommend using TypeScript with Hooks 
check this https://levelup.gitconnected.com/usetypescript-a-complete-guide-to-react-hooks-and-typescript-db1858d1fb9c